# Connecting vscode to remote failed, SSH client doesn't support PTY

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to connect to an ssh server using vscode and the error seems to be

```
Error: Your SSH client doesn't support PTY
```

I also tried to connect using openssh and activating PTY by providing small `-t` (this works) and capital `-T` (this throws the error).

I am using openSSH version Version 9.5p1-1. Is there any aditional configuration that I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried to use some extension in order to see if the problem persist? Like "remote - ssh"

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev Yes, Remote - SSH is installed

Comment: An SSH session can request a PTY or not request it, at the option of the client. If vscode thought it needed a PTY, I'd expect vscode to ask for a PTY. Do you know why the remote server is complaining about this? Do you know what is being done through ssh that requires a PTY?

Comment: @Kenster I assume PTY is needed for VScode to work, but I am unsure what the reason is. I dont know why the remote server is complaining about it though, it is an ubuntu server, this is the dockerfile used: https://hub.docker.com/layers/runpod/kasm-docker/cuda11/images/sha256-00d5d3433f505553a74fea749056a048090018dc2da0d49b26552914942b9cef?context=explore